# Impala authentication by username

Tags: jdbc, impala, kudu

I try to connect impala with jdbc connector with authentication by username and URL

```
 jdbc:impala://my-server-ip:21050/default;AuthMech=2;UID=impala;
```

but there is no response ?
any help please

Comment: Your command is fine. How is your authentication set ? AuthMech=2 will work if you set it up correctly. What are   messages when you issue above command or nothing at all and cursor coming back to prompt again? You can refer to this doc https://docs.cloudera.com/documentation/other/connectors/impala-jdbc/latest/Cloudera-JDBC-Driver-for-Impala-Install-Guide.pdf

Comment: nothing at all and cursor come back and I can write or exit .. but I did not  set authentication at impala but my user is impala